# Navigate xml nodes;

Tags: c#

Hi I have an xml data returned from another service. It looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response xmlns="http://test.com/group/application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Response>
<Response>
<ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
<Message>Sucess</Message>
<Data>PRINT 'This is a test #2'</Data>
</Response>
</Response>
</response>
```

I need the value of Data, Message and ReturnCode. The value inside the Data(PRINT 'This is a test #2') node could be single line or thousands of lines..

I am using this C# code to get the values

XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();

```
        string Response = obj.getContent(str, 1, 73810, SHA);



        //Console.WriteLine("Response" + Response);
        xm.LoadXml(Response);



        Console.WriteLine(xm.InnerXml);

        XmlNode oldCd;
        XmlElement root = xm.DocumentElement;
        Console.WriteLine(root.InnerText);
        oldCd = root.SelectSingleNode("/response/Response/Response/ReturnCode/Message/Data/");
```

---

```
static void Main()
    {
        try
        {

            svc obj = new svc();
          ..
            //XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();

            string rsp = obj.getContent(..;


            String myEncodedString;
            myEncodedString = obj.XmlDecode(rsp);

            XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://xxxx.com/xxx/xx");

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myEncodedString);

            Console.WriteLine(obj.Return_Message_Data("ReturnCode", myEncodedString));

            Console.WriteLine(obj.Return_Message_Data("Message", myEncodedString));

            Console.WriteLine(obj.Return_Message_Data("Data", myEncodedString));               

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You'd better start coding then!

Comment: Yes, I am accessing this from a c# application. I am

            XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
               
                string Rsp = obj.getContent(str, 1, 73810, SHA);
                xm.LoadXml(Rsp);              

                Console.WriteLine(xm.InnerXml);

                XmlNode oldCd;
                XmlElement root = xm.DocumentElement;
                Console.WriteLine(root.InnerText);
                oldCd = root.SelectSingleNode("/response/Response/Response/ReturnCode/Message/Data/");

But I don't see any value in the Data column. 
Thanks

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. This sounds more like you want an entire solution.

Comment: are you loading the XML as a string or reading from a file. Please provide some detail or source of input from your question.

Comment: I am reading it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); //myXmlString is the xml file in string //copying xml to string: string myXmlString = xmldoc.OuterXml.ToString();
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/responset[@*]/Response");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
XmlNode response = xn.SelectSingleNode("Response");
if (response != null)
{
string rc = response["ReturnCode"].InnerText;
string msg = example["Message"].InnerText;
string data = example["Data"].InnerText;
}
}
```